# Get application url from DI with Nest.js

Tags: nestjs

In the main.ts we can get the application url with app.getUrl().

Is is possible to get it from a service via DI ?

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    await app.listen(3000);
    console.log(`Application is running on: ${await app.getUrl()}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `app` variable outside of bootstrap method and export it:

```js
export let app: INestApplication;
    
async function bootstrap() {
    app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    await app.listen(3000);
    console.log(`Application is running on: ${await app.getUrl()}`);
}
bootstrap();
```